# Adding index to the column already having an index

Tags: sybase-asa

there are indexes available for each columns. for ex: indx1 on col1 and indx2 on col2.  is it possible to create again a composite index indx3 by combining col1 and col2? 
col1 and col2 are used in the where condition. will indx3 is in effect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the query optimizer will look for the best matching index. If you include `col1` and `col2` in a composite index and query (`where`) for those two fields it will use this index.

You should also consider throwing away the index on `col1` because the composite index can be used for queries on `col1` too. It depends on the sequence of the columns in the composite index: the first column can queried without the second one.